# Configure Virtual Printer Port Redirection

Tags: c#, port, printer-properties, virtual-printer

I need to configure a virtual printer port to redirect it to a external program(.exe file) through c# code. 
Right now I am able to install a virtual port with some customization(thanks to [bghh](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/a901406f-7a38-43a2-a970-dab9d52cb0f3/) code).
The attached picture illustrates the requirement. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Configuring virtual printer port redirection manually]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out solution to the above problem.
All the printer ports registered on the system are listed in registry under the key "*SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Print\Monitors\Redirected Port\Ports*"

Values under these keys can be edited to get the desired result. Below is the code to edit it using c#.

```
bool found = false;
string portName = "testing:";
RegistryKey PrinterPort = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control\\Print\\Monitors\\Redirected Port\\Ports", true);
foreach (string pp in PrinterPort.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    if (pp == portName)
    {
        PrinterPort = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Control\\Print\\Monitors\\Redirected Port\\Ports"+"\\"+portName, true);
        found = true; break;
    }
}
if (found)
{
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"Arguments", "@C:\\gs\\pdfwrite.txt -sOutputFile=\"d:\\hello.pdf\" -c .setpdfwrite -f -");
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"Command", "c:\\gs\\bin\\gswin32c.exe");
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"Delay", 0x12c);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"LogFileDebug", 0x0);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"LogFileName", "");
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"LogFileUse", 0x0);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"Output", 0x0);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"Printer", "Send To Cool Printer");
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"PrintError", 0x0);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"RunUser", 0x0);
    PrinterPort.SetValue(@"ShowWindow", 0x0);
}
PrinterPort.Close();
```

Comment: I am trying to setup a virtual printer to print from applications then redirect a PostScript to my own workflow. I am not sure what the whole process is to achieve this or the tasks involved, it seems there are 2 parts, the driver and the monitor. The info above seems it about the monitor is that correct? I have the above code creating the Registry entries, although I cannot see the port if I try and create a driver manually.

Comment: I find this code confusing, why is the `foreach` loop there?  It appears to serve no purpose, and could be greatly simplified.  Forgive my C#, but isn't this functionally equivalent? http://ideone.com/YAmUO6