# Add my C# windows application as a printer in windows

Tags: c#

I am a fresher in c#. I have developed an application that can convert a postscript file(.ps) to formats like PDF,JPEG, ets,. My intention is to develop a pdf printer. So how do I add this application as a printer in windows xp or above. Or say how do I get the PS file when CTRL+P is pressed on any windows application.

This is not a network printer, its a printer that needs to be assigned to a local print port and not a network port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking, how to make a virtual printer in C#, a very good question, and an easy one, you can use some thing called:
- Virtual Printer Port Redirection, you can see the following questions and articles, they are very related to yours:

[Writing a Virtual Printer in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257768/writing-a-virtual-printer-in-net)

[Configure Virtual Printer Port Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10403805/configure-virtual-printer-port-redirection)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/br259124

Comment: This was really helpful, but can you suggest a way to get a job from the print queue, I need the postscript of the job as the input to my app.