# receiving print job and send it to a real printer, like a gateway

Tags: c#, printing

is there a way to created a fake/virtual printer? so that our users will be able to choose it, and send their print jobs to it, and then let the c# application receive the job, and send that job to a real printer, with other properties?

my biggest wish is that i don't have to play with drivers, but of course, i don't think i can avoid that, as long as i don't have to write that thing my own... :D

Comment: Do your users have client software?  Do you have a server as well?

Comment: client software? they will use excel/word that needs to be printet;
Server is not a problem, it will be put to use in a company

Comment: As long as your virtual printer and the actual hardware printer selected are of the same type (Postscript, raster, plain text, etc) and share similar characteristics (color vs B&W, printable area, supported paper sizes, resident fonts), this is fairly easy to do with a port monitor.  You won't be able to avoid a print driver, but you only need the Microsoft sample driver from the WDK.  You'll have to supply your own .INF and .PPD/.GPD files, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> printer++ is a flexible and powerful windows virtual printer that
>   allows you to print from any application (excel, webpages, word…) and
>   then have the print job sent to a printer++ SDK solution tailored to
>   your needs and requirements.

[PrinterPlusPlus](http://www.printerplusplus.com/) seems like an option, there is also [Virtual Printer](http://www.colorpilot.com/emfprinterpilot.html)

Another way would be to redirect it, [here you can see an example of it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421099/342740) but might not be as simple as making your own.

Comment: I cant seem to see a site a www.PrinterPlusPLus.com for a couple of days, is this still supported?

Comment: @prix sir, PrinterPlusPlus is no more (they have discontinued it) and the other solution you mentioned is too pricey.  do you mind to share a link where i can find the printerplusplus the latest binary release along with sdk and guide?